Setting the color of a MapPolyline to the app's accent color
I am trying to set the color of a MapPolyline to the app's accent color using .stroke().
I have tried extending ShapeStyle to have a custom definition for accent color:
extension ShapeStyle where Self == Color {
    static var accentColor: Color { Color.accentColor }
}

And modifying the MapPolyline as follows:
MapPolyline(route.route)
    .stroke(.accentColor, lineWidth: 5)

However, this leads the MapPolyline to still have the default blue color, instead of my app's accent color.
I have also tried to use the .tint ShapeStyle, and setting the accent color with .tint(Color.accentColor as an additional modifier, but this also did not work.

This might be an iOS bug, since this works correctly on macOS.
A workaround is to resolve the color in the view's environment, and use the resolved color:
@Environment(\.self) var env

var body: some View {
    Map {
        MapPolyline(...)
            .stroke(Color.accentColor.resolve(in: env), lineWidth: 5)
    }
}


You can write this as a MapContent extension:
extension MapContent {
    func strokeResolved(_ content: some ShapeStyle, style: StrokeStyle = .init()) -> some MapContent {
        Stroked(content: self, stroke: content, strokeStyle: style)
    }

    func strokeResolved(_ content: some ShapeStyle, lineWidth: CGFloat) -> some MapContent {
        strokeResolved(content, style: .init(lineWidth: lineWidth))
    }
}

struct Stroked<Content: MapContent, Style: ShapeStyle>: MapContent {
    @Environment(\.self) var env
    
    let content: Content
    let stroke: Style
    let strokeStyle: StrokeStyle
    
    var body: some MapContent {
        content.stroke(stroke.resolve(in: env), style: strokeStyle)
    }
}

// usage:
.strokeResolved(.accentColor, lineWidth: 5)

